# authenticating to 'management.azure.com' with msal

Tags: adal, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to use `MSAL with angular` to query the list of tenants available to a user. I was previously successfully using `adal.js`.

This is the request URL: `https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2019-11-01`
MSAL successfully injects a bearer token into the request.
However, I see the following error in www-authenticate:

> www-authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/", error="invalid_token", error_description="Could not find identity for access token."

I'm a little confused by this error - `login.windows.net` appears to be part of a deprecated authentication flow.

I've got `'https://management.azure.com/', ['user_impersonation']` inside my protectedResourceMap.
I've tried setting the authority to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}` as well as the default. The clientId, tenant, etc, have not been changed from ADAL.

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For adal(**v1.0 endpoint**), we need to use `resource: https://management.azure.com`. The authority url is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize`.

For msal(**v2.0 endpint**), we need to use `scope:https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation`. The authority url is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`.